# I wanna get notification only, do not launch app

Tags: android

This is my code:
It works awesomely but it launches an application on getting notification. Just I don't want that. I wanna get the notification but do not launch the app.

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent2, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"default")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.orgnic_farm)
                .setContentTitle("EFarm Says!")
                .setContentText("Hey!, Your Order will be Delivered to you Today.")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        NotificationManager notificationManagerCompat= (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            builder.setChannelId("com.myApp");
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    "com.myApp",
                    "My App",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );
            if (notificationManagerCompat != null) {
                notificationManagerCompat.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
        }
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(100,builder.build());
```

Comment: Its not written by you, correct? Do you understand this code?

Comment: not written by me i analyzed it little bit. If my app is terminated and i get the notification it automatically launch the app, which i do not want

Comment: Then why are you passing intent to main activity via pending intent

Comment: Dude I was added that afterword and that was for launch the activity when I click on notification. Its working perfectly also but as terminate my app and at the time of notification automatically it launches the app and that I don't want. That's the my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Actually it's working fine but i have used firebase phone auth and while launching the app i always check is it logged in already or not if already logged then it will launch home activity else it will goes to login activity. So that's why when notification comes it will launch my home activity.

Comment: Now someone get the idea about how should both work then tell me.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, **only on tapping the notification** your app will be launched and the MainActivity will be displayed. It won't automatically launch the app if you receive the notification.

If you don't want the app to be launched on tapping the notification then just remove the line `setContentIntent()`.

Comment: Yes I know that, But apart from that my app is getting launched at the time of notification.

Comment: Are you trying to implement remote push notification? If so then you might be using FCM's onMessageReceived callback where you would have written your above code. In that case there is no possibility of your app getting launched when you just receive the notification.

Comment: Actually I am generating notification on specific time

Comment: like: Intent intent1=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ReminderBroadcast.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0,intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,10000,pendingIntent);

Comment: Is that reason for that?

Comment: Yes, that might be the cause for it. AlarmManager wakes the app while running your code if your app is not running.

Comment: Damn, Is there anything else which I can use and schedule notification

Comment: Try using OneTimeWorkrequest of WorkManager API. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager

Comment: Same thing is happening with this one also.

Comment: Kindly post your complete code of that class if possible to check